# writeUTF not working :/

Tags: java, sockets, udp

im coding a client that sends a file using DatagramSocket (UDP), but first we need to send the name of the file to the server using writeUTF(). Both client and server, compile and run without any error, but seems like the filename never arrives the server. Any idea of what could be happening? I post the code below...

Thanks :)

**Client.java**

```
     ...
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;)
                    {
                        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                    } 

                    // File data
                    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
                                //file is a String with the name of the file
                    dos.writeUTF(file);
//Setting up DatagramSocket
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
        ...
```

**Server.java**

```
...
        almacen = new byte[MAXNOMBREFICHERO + 2];
        packet = new DatagramPacket( almacen, almacen.length );

    System.out.println("\nWaiting client...");
    socket.receive(packet);
    dirIPClient = packet.getAddress();
        clientPort = packet.getPort();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( almacen );
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( bais );

        filename = dis.readUTF();
...
```

Comment: You are adding the filename after you have taking a snapshot of the bytes so it won't be in the `data` but even if it was, it would be at the end, not the start so reading it the way you do wouldn't help.  Why not write it at the start the way you read it?

Answer (score 0):

You write the file contents to `bos` and convert it to a byte array. So you now got the file contents in `data`. You write `file` to `bos` after converting the stream to a byte array, so the file name is not included. Call `writeUTF` before writing the actual file contents to `bos`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

// file is a String with the name of the file
dos.writeUTF(file);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
    dos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
}

// Packet data
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

// Setting up DatagramPacket
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
socket.send(packet);
```

Comment: After dos.writeUTF(file) is `//Setting up DatagramSocket
   DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
        socket.send(packet);` i forgot to post it

Comment: not working, server still waiting for that String :/

So, we put the bytes of the String in the first place and then the file data, that makes sense to me, thanks :)

Now, i have to understand why its not reading that String the server :s

Comment: Does the server receive the packet?

Comment: Nope, i change server java with if (socket.receive(packet)) System.out.println("received");

and the server still showing Waiting Client...

Answer (score 0):

You never send the contents of `dos` over the wire. `dos` is hooked up to `bos` so any content written to `dos` will go to the `byte[]` that `bos` is associated with. Furthermore, you extract the contents of `bos` *before* you make that call to `writeUTF`... this is not a live connection; it's a one-time thing. So by calling `writeUTF` after extracting the array contents, you ensure that the `file` will not be in that array. If you call `writeUTF` and **then** call `bos.toByteArray()` you'll have the filename in the array (but it will be last in the array, not first).